# Is the google chrome extension I made insecure in any way?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

my organization uses cisco finesse and when we connect to the phones from home, we use a nailed connection to our cell phones. When you receive a call in finesse, there is no audible queue meaning no ringing at all when you get a call. There are server side solutions in cisco documentation, however, my IT department has refused to do anything about it. This problem affects hundreds of users but there is no interest in fixing it.

Que me, the greenest developer on these forums, trying to find a solution for my office. I am learning about the request response cycle, php, java, css and html... and I see a get request in chrome developer tools that comes in all the time when you get a call, so I figured out how to write a chrome extension in javascript to solve the ringing problem by playing a sound when that get request gets sent. Here is the code. Please let me know if it is insecure or if I should change it in any way to make it better. My mp3 is from Spaceballs if that matters.

`background.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
      if (details.method === 'GET' && details.url === 'my url is here') {
        var audio = new Audio('ringtone.mp3');
        audio.play();
      }
    },
    {urls: ['<all_urls>']},
    ['blocking']
  );
```

` Manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Make finesse ring",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Plays a sound when a specific GET request is made.",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "my url is here "
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}`
```